# PST-pulley not showing correctly

Tags: xetex

I was trying to use the package *pst-pulley* as described in this [pdf](https://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-pulley/pst-pulley-doc.pdf) and other resource which lead to the following code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20mm,12pt,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-pulley}
\begin{document}
\pspulleys[N=3,M=60,h=25]
\end{document}
```

Used the `XeLaTeX` option available in the *TexWorks* editor. But reached the following pdf:
[image]

Would like to have something similar to the pdf linked above:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you use the `--shell-escape`  switch for xelatex?

Comment: @Bernard I didn't used, but tried to research about it and configured TexWorks in the following way: https://imgur.com/a/pjsDPRv . Still got the same output. Tried to switch the order around but nothing

Comment: I tested the code, & the only way that seems to work is the traditional way: `latex -> dvi -> ps`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your help! it worked. I didn't find the dvi2ps option in the TexWorks but was able to find it in the Texmaker editor. After some more fidling around with the ps2pdf, I finally got the pdf.

Comment: Fine!  I'm glad for you!